# JMeter loop through different Test Methods

Tags: jmeter

I want to test my REST service within one Test Plan and one Thread Group.

There are two methods. Let's call it getConfiguration and getDefinitionList. Both have different parameters in the URL and as header. That's why I created a CSV file for both of them. The first CSV file contains five lines for the different test cases, the second only three.

I added a CSV Data Set Config to both methods.
I want JMeter to perform the first method five times and then the second, three times. Then the thread is to be terminated.

Without an additional controller, the first method is executed once, then the second one, then the first and so on. With the second one there are of course errors, because the CSV file has only three lines.

I thought a loop controller might help, but can't get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

1. Put your 1st method under [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set `Loop Count` to `5`
2. Do the same for 2nd method, but this time set `Loop Count` to `3`
3. Move [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) elements **as children** of the HTTP Request methods

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

Comment: I had that idea, but what if the CSV file is changed by a tester? I want it dynamic... is this possible?

Comment: Then replace Loop Controller with the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) with the condition of `${__javaScript("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}` and configure your CSV Data Set Configs to not to recycle on EOF and not to stop thread on EOF

Comment: Did that. Thought that myVar is a column from the CSV right? `${__javaScript("${Description}" != "<EOF>",)}`. The While Controller then runs 6 times with an assertion error at the sixth run because it is unable the send a correct sixth request...

Comment: Man, I gave you an idea, you should be able to polish it according to your requirements, moreover the references contain all the instructions. Put your HTTP Request under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use `"${myVar}" != "<EOF>"` as the condition. And yes, `myVar` stands for one of the JMeter Variables defined in the "Variable Names" section of the CSV Data Set Config, amend it as required.

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest each [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) inside the While Controller due to Scoping rules:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules

And set sharing in CSV Data Set config to **Current Thread Group**

Example:

[image]

CSV Data Set configured like this , pay attention to each config:

[image]

While Controller1 condition :

> ${__jexl3("${name1}" != "",)}

While Controller1 condition : ${__jexl3("${name1}" != "",)}

> ${__jexl3("${name2}" != "",)}

If Controller1 condition and check "**Interpret Condition as Variable Expression**":

> ${__jexl3("${name1}" != "",)}

If Controller2 condition and check "**Interpret Condition as Variable Expression**":

> ${__jexl3("${name2}" != "",)}

Comment: That is right, but not the full solution. As @Dmitri T showed, there are two Look Controller but that is not dynamic... depending an the lines in the csv that may change

Comment: That's what I meant, see my updated answer which also answers your comment on the other answer